# how to catch parameters using Getx in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, parameters, flutter-getx, flutter-navigation

I am working on flutter route

here is my code

```
import 'package:flutter_application_shop/pages/home/food/popular_food.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_shop/pages/home/main_food_page.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';


class RouteHelper {
  static const String popularFood = "/popular-food";


  static String getPopularFood(int pageId) => '$popularFood?pageId?=$pageId';

  static List<GetPage> routes = [
    GetPage(
        name: popularFood,
        page: () {
          var pageId = Get.parameters['pageId'];

          return PopularFoodPage(pageId: int.parse(pageId!));
        },
        transition: Transition.circularReveal),
    
  ];


}
```

running this code I got a correct route of **/popular-food?pageId?=1** for instance but the id is not passed to the screen. I always get this error

[image]

I noticed that the **int.parse(pageId!)** returns an empty result. if I remove **!** flutter will throw an error. Please I need assistance on this.

Comment: add the snippet from where you are calling the route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem comes from **'$popularFood?pageId?=$pageId';** try removing the second **?** and try again.

Try this

```
static String getPopularFood(int pageId) => '$popularFood?pageId=$pageId';
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove null checker operator and try if not solve then add null checker outside